# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken Method not calling in iOS7

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I am using apple push notifications in my applications,requesting for the  device token with

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

When it prompts alert like Do you want  to allow push notifications if i click Don't allow in iOS6, Still it calls the "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" delegate method and gives DeviceToken,But the same is not happening in iOS7.When i tried the same in iOS7 the delegate method is not calling and no DeviceToken is generating. 
The device token is very important to me, as i am using the token in registration process. 
Please let me know that why device token is not generating in iOS7, does apple change anything on device token requests from iOS6 to iOS7.

Comment: This could very well be intended. If the user does not wish to accept push notifications, there's no need to register with the APS. This could be an optimisation for iOS7. As such, you shouldn't rely on the token provided for user registration with your service, it should be optional.

Comment: So it is change from Apple right?Can u provide some references for this.

Comment: Is `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` delegate method invoked?